# .net compare CSV files

Tags: .net, vb.net

I have two CSV files. One contains a time punches and default pay rate information. The other file contains any rates that are different from the default pay rate based on the job they worked, location etc.

So I may have a default rate of $16 an hour but when I work at location B doing Job XYZ I am paid $19 an hour. Right now I have it all working just fine however it is incredibly slow and resource heavy as I am looping through the 2nd CSV file for each and every lookup. The first file has about 10-20k lines in it each time its processed and the 2nd has around 1100.

Maybe my coffee hasn't kicked in yet but there has to be a better way to do the compare.

Also once we do the compare I need to potentially change one field in the first CSV file. I couldnt find a way to do the write like I would for a datareaderadapter so my plan was to just genereate a new CSV on the fly and replace the original. Is there a better way for that?

```
        Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(punchdatafile)
            MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
            MyReader.SetDelimiters(",")
            Dim currentRow As String()
            Do While Not MyReader.EndOfData
                Try
                    currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields
                    Dim d_field0 As String = currentRow(0) 'EmployeeID
                    Dim d_field3 As String = currentRow(3) 'Jobcode
                    Dim d_field4 As String = currentRow(4) 'Punchdate
                    Dim d_field7 As String = currentRow(7) 'PayRate
                    Dim d_field11 As String = currentRow(11) 'Location

                    Using Rate_Reader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(ratedatafile)
                        Rate_Reader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
                        Rate_Reader.SetDelimiters(",")
                        Rate_Reader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True

                        Dim rate_currentrow As String()
                        Do While Not Rate_Reader.EndOfData
                            rate_currentrow = Rate_Reader.ReadFields
                            Dim r_field1 As String = rate_currentrow(1) 'RateID
                            Dim r_field3 As String = rate_currentrow(3) 'Rate
                            Dim r_field4 As String = rate_currentrow(4) 'RateJobCode
                            Dim r_field6 As String = rate_currentrow(6) 'RateDate
                            Dim r_field9 As String = rate_currentrow(9) 'RateLocation

                            If d_field0 = r_field1 Then 'OK we got an Employee ID to match
                                If d_field3 = r_field4 Then 'Getting there, Job Code Matches
                                    If d_field11 = r_field9 Then 'We are there. Location matches too!
                                        Console.WriteLine(r_field3)
                                    End If
                                End If
                            End If
                        Loop
                    End Using

                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try
            Loop
        End Using
```

Code above works as expected just incredibly slow.

### UPDATE

After coffee kicked in I decided to load the 2nd file (one I am doing lookups against) into a datatable at runtime and then do a datatable.select against it row by row for my first file. Lightning fast now. Still leaves the question of is there a way to update a field in the CSV file as I am looping through it or will I need to just rewrite the entire file as I am iterating through it.

Here is my update code:

```
      Dim dt As DataTable = New DataTable
        Dim dr As DataRow

        dt.Columns.Add("id")
        dt.Columns.Add("rate")
        dt.Columns.Add("jobcode")
        dt.Columns.Add("location")
        dt.Columns.Add("date")

        Using Rate_Reader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(ratedatafile)
            Rate_Reader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
            Rate_Reader.SetDelimiters(",")
            Rate_Reader.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = True

            Dim rate_currentrow As String()
            Do While Not Rate_Reader.EndOfData
                rate_currentrow = Rate_Reader.ReadFields
                Dim r_field1 As String = rate_currentrow(1) 'RateID
                Dim r_field3 As String = rate_currentrow(3) 'Rate
                Dim r_field4 As String = rate_currentrow(4) 'RateJobCode
                Dim r_field6 As String = rate_currentrow(6) 'RateDate
                Dim r_field9 As String = rate_currentrow(9) 'RateLocation

                dr = dt.NewRow

                dr("id") = r_field1
                dr("rate") = r_field3
                dr("jobcode") = r_field4
                dr("location") = r_field9
                dr("date") = r_field6

                dt.Rows.Add(dr)
            Loop
        End Using


        Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser(punchdatafile)
            MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
            MyReader.SetDelimiters(",")
            Dim currentRow As String()
            Do While Not MyReader.EndOfData
                Try
                    currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields
                    Dim d_field0 As String = currentRow(0) 'EmployeeID
                    Dim d_field3 As String = currentRow(3) 'Jobcode
                    Dim d_field4 As String = currentRow(4) 'Punchdate
                    Dim d_field7 As String = currentRow(7) 'PayRate
                    Dim d_field11 As String = currentRow(11) 'Location

                    Dim searchdr() As System.Data.DataRow
                    searchdr = dt.Select("id='" & d_field0 & "' AND jobcode='" & d_field3 & "' AND location='" & d_field11 & "'")
                    If searchdr.Length > 0 Then
                        Console.WriteLine(searchdr(0)("rate").ToString)
                    End If


                Catch ex As Exception

                End Try
            Loop
        End Using
```

Comment: Why use a CSV file and try to do a job (searches) with it for which is not suitable? Load your files in a database, apply correct indexes and execute searches on the db.

Comment: loaded the 2nd file into a datatable. Still need to find best way to update a field in the first file or is rewriting the whole file best way?

Comment: A DataTable is an in-memory object. You solve nothing (memory wise) with it. You should use a real database software like SqLite to create your db, then load the CSV once on a db table and finally use ADO.NET to query (search) your data

Comment: 20k lines of text is nothing. Create a couple of Data Tables for each file, add the fields you need to calculate to Table 1, set up a relation with Table 2, do the calculations and write out the CSV afterward. If, once coded, the entire process takes more than a split second I'd be surprised.

Comment: I think your general approach is correct. Load the CSV file into a DataTable, then make changes on the DataTable, and re-write the entire CSV file back out. Since CSV file has variable-length fields, you won't easily be able to change data in the middle of an existing file. Easier to rewrite the whole thing.

Comment: I recommend writing two generic routines 1) csv-to-datatable and 2) datatable-to-csv. You will reuse these over and over again, since it is a cheap way to send/receive data with Excel. PROTIP: for any accounting package, add an Export to CSV option for every grid. Accountants will love you for it, because Excel is their happy place.